What is the correct way to handle input prompts from Git using Python's subprocess?
I have a Python script that is responsible for backing up git repositories. It basically pulls a list of all repos in a org (Azure DevOps/GitHub) and clones all repos in that list.
The issue is that when running the script via terminal it prompts for token/password and I have to manually input the token even though the script should be able to handle it. Git is not accepting inputs from Python's subprocess.
Code:
import os
import subprocess
URL = 'myorg.com'


GIT_TOKEN = os.environ['GIT_TOKEN']
try:
    #OMITTED: for loop to fetch repo endpoints
    for repo in repos:
        REPO = repo['repoURL']
    # input= is added in run() function
        cmd = subprocess.run(['git', 'clone', REPO], input=GIT_TOKEN+'\n', encoding='utf-8', shell=False)
        # as pointed out, .communicate() was used in error. 
        #stout, sterr = cmd.communicate(input=(GIT_TOKEN+'\r', timeout=5)

except Exception as err:
    print('error: ', err)

Couple of things I think are causing the issue:

git commands are executing faster than Python can handle or git is blocking inputs from Python.
subprocess is not parsing inputs to git - (do subprocess inputs need encoding?), don't think so otherwise it would throw an error.

Not sure what else I can do to troubleshoot this script or why it's not working.
Is my code not working or is this more a lack of understanding git's functionalities?
Note: Tokens are generated dynamically when script are run and work - the issue is parsing inputs to git using python.
EDIT: fixed some typos, added comments and removed incorrect use of communicate() method as pointed out in the comments.

You misspelled encoding so I doubt this is your actual code. Why are you using \r instead of \n to terminate the input? For the record, there is no way for a subprocess to run "too fast"

What is wrong with using a bare except?

Also, there is no way to communicate with the object returned by run; you are mixing the Popen and the run APIs. You should pass input='...' to run directly.

yep, that was a typo...
wrt what is wrong with except... that's just how I usually catch exceptions. A better way would be to also include a finally block.

If the username and token/password are available, you can embed them in the repo URL. The username depends on the remote server. For example, in Gitlab it could be either an account or the literal oauth2.
# Suppose the URL is https://myorg.com/foo/bar.git

username = 'accfoo'
token = 'sAb5ufmGegMp28Xas6Px'
stout, sterr = subprocess.run(
    ['git', 'clone', f'https://{username}:{token}@myorg.com/foo/bar.git'],
    enconding='utf-8',
    shell=False).communicate()

You can also use a credential helper to cache the username and token/password, so that you don't need to deal with them in the script.
